# How to prove that a quadratic equation implies both variables are zero

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus

This might be really simple, but I can't find how to prove that

$a^2-\frac{2}{3} ab+b^2=0$

implies that both $a$ and $b$ are zero.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Do you know the quadratic formula?

Comment: Note: there are nonzero solutions to this equation, but they involve complex numbers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**A start:** Complete the square. The left side is equal to $\left(a-\frac{b}{3}\right)^2+ \frac{8b^2}{9}$.

**Remarks:** $1$. If you like symmetry (and what mathematician doesn't?), note that we want to show that $3a^2-2ab+3b^2=0$ has no non-trivial real solutions. But
$$3a^2-2ab+3b^2=2a^2+2b^2+(a-b)^2.$$

$2$. Of course there are solutions other than $(0,0)$ in the complex numbers.

Comment: I should have noted that... After completing the square, both terms are square, so both are positive, so both equal zero, so b is zero, and from that, a must be zero too. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome. Yes, you have the right argument, except that instead of positive you should say non-negative.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: start by completing the square:

$$\left(a-\frac b3\right)^2+\frac 89b^2=0$$

What does this tell you about the values that are possible for $a,b$?

Comment: Thanks, completing the squares makes it easier to see